# SD Card with SDIO Interface Issues on STM32F446RET6 PCB

Tags: stm32, sd, stm32cubeide, sdio

We are currently working on a PCB that has an [STM32F446RET6](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f446re.pdf) MCU. The PCB is equipped with various sensors for data collection. Additionally, we are using an SD card for data logging and have opted for the SDIO interface for the SD card. However, we are experiencing instability issues with the SD card (not working sometimes), and we haven't been able to resolve the problem despite trying different values for pull-up resistors and using a 10µF capacitor for the 3V3 line. None of these attempts have solved the problem. In addition, we have four identical cards, and one of them mostly works fine, while the other only works when cooled down. The remaining two cards, with the exact same setup and software, do not work at all. Additionally, the f_open function consistently returns the FR_DISK_ERR error every 15 to 20 seconds.

[image]

[image]

[image]

CLX pin of SDIO:

[image]

CMD and DAT0 pins of the SDIO:
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please show your PCB layout as well.

Comment: Have you done measurements with a scope? I've solved a similar problem with a SD card interface by triggering the scope when a read or write error happens. This allowed me to see the exactly what happened on the data lines when the error occured. In my case it was actually a software error related to the sleep function of the MCU.

Comment: @TimWilliams  I added the layout

Comment: That's a small part of the layout; what about the rest of the route? How is the MCU wired? | GND pads appear unconnected. Is there a polygon on top? Bottom? Is there a mid layer? | Your oscilloscope is likely too slow to read signal quality issues; this can require >200MHz bandwidth. You also require a 10x or "low-Z" probe to resolve these events (check manual for 1x probe bandwidth).

Comment: @nanash1 we measure pins with scope. I added the pictures

Comment: Have you tried increasing SDIOCLK clock divider?

Comment: Your measurements are done with probes in 1x mode. The results you see on scope screen are flawed. Do not use probes in 1x mode, use 10x probes. Only use probes in 1x mode if you know what you are doing and know you need to use probes in 1x mode.

Comment: Add an X7R decoupling capacitor close to the SD card socket between pin 4 and 6.

Comment: @Justme I updated the scope pictures with 10x scope ones. In what conditions should ı use 1x mode?

Comment: @RohatKılıç we tried the clock divider values in range of 0-10 and none of them work

Comment: @BurakKayaalp General scope measurements won't do much good. My advice was to trigger the scope when an error in the SD interface occurs. Use a free gpio pin as scope trigger. Also, you don't describe the problem very well. What happens exactly when the instability issues occurs? Do you get CRC errors? Does the card stop responding? Does the card de-init?

Comment: @Jens Not actually necessary, or, not always required at least; SD cards are allowed to have up to 8.2uF onboard. Much to the surprise of users hot-plugging cards for the first time (causing system reset due to the momentary power drop). The apparent lack of ground in the layout is highly disturbing though.

Comment: @TimWilliams Good to know, I never expected such big capacitors inside the card. But this would explain why the card works somehow without GND, recharging by low input levels.

Comment: @TimWilliams  In both the bottom and top layers of the circuit, there is a ground polygon, meaning that the SD card's ground connection is present.